# Coding lane information with multiple directions but only one matched direction with HERE api

Tags: here-api

Is there any sample code for me to implement the lane guidance similar to this where part of the direction of one particular lane information would not match the current maneuver and I would have to do a partial faded out icon like this. The existing lane information doesn't cover such scenario automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is related to HERE Premium Mobile SDK for Adnroid, the LaneInformation call back provides the Matching direction and recommendation state relevant to the current route which should help to achieve the requirement.

[LaneInformation.getMatchedDirection()](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/content/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/guidance/LaneInformation.html#getMatchedDirection--) 
[LaneInformation.getRecommendationState()](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/content/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/guidance/LaneInformation.html#getRecommendationState--)

[image]